# Typescript function returns NaN value but number type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have this countdown timer function:

```
startTimer(duration) {
        this.myTimer = duration;
        setInterval(function () {
            this.myTimer--;
            console.log("TIMER: "+ typeof(this.myTimer) + " "+this.myTimer);
        }, 1000);
    }
```

which I call in this way: `this.startTimer(60);`

This is the result of `console.log`: `TIMER: number NaN`.
So `typeof(this.myTimer)` returns `number` type and when I print its value I get `NaN`.

Why do I get `NaN`?

Note: I'm using Angular2 (typescript) and I've defined `myTimer` variable inside the component class right before the constructor in this simple way:

```
export class myComponent {
myTimer;
constructor(private navCtrl: NavController) {}
 // my code (previous function is here)
}
```

Comment: `typeof NaN` is `"number"`

Comment: You usually get NaN when you do operation on number with other typers like string. Mayber you are mutating string somewhere else to be string?

Comment: In `setInterval` handler function, `this-context` is not what you are expecting...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like Rayon said in the comments, in your `setTimeout` function callback you have a different `this` as in your `startTimer` function, so `myTimer` isn't a member of it. `undefined` becomes `NaN` after the `--` operation.

To fix it you can either use the `var that = this` trick or use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```
function startTimer(duration) {
    this.myTimer = duration;
    setInterval(() => {
        this.myTimer--;
        console.log("TIMER: "+ typeof(this.myTimer) + " "+this.myTimer);
    }, 1000);
}
```